# How to do Terraform plan in Bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: terraform, bitbucket-pipelines, azure-rm

Trying to deploy first bb pipe with terraform on azure cloud.
Terraform INIT goes OK. But as soon as you get to Plan or Apply it fails.
BB pipeline:

```
image: hashicorp/terraform:latest

pipelines:
  default:
        - step:
            name: Test
            script:
                - terraform init -backend-config="storage_account_name=$DEV_TF_CONFIG_STORAGE_ACCOUNT" -backend-config="container_name=$DEV_TF_CONFIG_CONTAINER_NAME" -backend-config="key=$DEV_TF_CONFIG_KEY" -backend-config="sas_token=$DEV_TF_SAS_TOKEN"
                - terraform plan 
                - terraform apply
```

Error for Terraform plan command:

```
+ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Invalid provider configuration
│ 
│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread" requires explicit
│ configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the
│ provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: could not configure AzureCli Authorizer: could not parse Azure CLI version: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in $PATH
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread"],
│   on <empty> line 0:
│   (source code not available)
│ 
╵
```

I'm fairly new to the subject :). Any ideas?

Comment: btw, provider block exist like this:  provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

subscription_id = var.subscription_id
tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
client_id       = var.client_id
client_secret   = var.client_secret
}

Answer (score 2):

this was solved by passing bitbucket repository variables: TF_VAR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, TF_VAR_TENANT_ID, TF_VAR_CLIENT_ID, TF_VAR_CLIENT_SECRET, TF_VAR_AKS_ADMIN_GROUP_ID to Terraform by specifying following code in variables.tf:

```
variable "SUBSCRIPTION_ID" {
}
variable "CLIENT_ID" {
}
variable "CLIENT_SECRET" {
}
variable "TENANT_ID" {
}
variable "AKS_ADMIN_GROUP_ID" {
}
```

the passing of values is done automatically from bitbucket to terraform, nothing should be done actually in the pipeline. all we needed to do is to define repo variables and alter the variables.tf

Comment: I was doing the same thing. Declared var's as you declared and passing them from repo var's. variable "SECRET_ID" {
}.
and still I am getting not declared error. Can you help mw out how you are passing in terraform plan step.
Error: No value for required variable
  on variables.tf line 4:
   4: variable "SECRET_ID" {